# Junit ant task not reporting assertion errors as failures

Tags: java, junit, ant, gitlab

I am trying to integrate my Junit test results in our gitlab pipeline. I have a successful ant build file that uses the Junit task and JUnit report tasks to create xml files that will integrate with gitlab.

I am using:
java 1.8,
ant 1.7.0,
junit 4.4

I am using a simple sample test class from this tutorial to test (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/junit_basic_usage.html) but I added an assertTrue(false).

Unit test:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.Assert.*;

public class MyUnitTest{
   @Test
   public void testConcatenate() {
       MyUnit myUnit= new MyUnit();
       String result = myUnit.concatenate("one","two");
        assertEquals("twoone", result);
   }
   @Test
   public void testAgain() {
       fail();
     }
}
```

My build script looks like this:

```
<project name ="JUnitTest" default = "test" basedir = "." > 
   <property name = "testdir" location = [location of dir} />
   <property name = "full-compile" value = "true" />
   <path ide - "classpath.test" >
      <pathelement location = "junit-4.4.jar" />
      <pathelement location = "${testdir}" />
    </path>
    <target name = compile" >
       <javac srcdir = "${srcdir}" destdir = "${testdir}" >
          <classpath refid ="classpath.test" />
       </javac>
     </target>
            
  <target name = "test" depends = "compile" >

    <junit haltonfailure ="no" >
    <classpath [my classpath here]>
    <formatted type = "xml" />
    <test name = "MyUnitTest" 
       todir = "${testdir}" />
    </junit>
 </target>
```

I am running with the command:
`ant -buildfile testBuild.xml`

The output to the command line reports the test as FAILED. However when I view the xml report, it says 0 Failures and 1 Error. When I run with the JUnitCore in the command line this also reports a failure rather than an error. I have verified that all the ort.junit.Assert statements result in an assertion error which reports in the test report as an error not a failure. Most documentation I can find says this should output a failure instead. The fail() does result in a failed test.

I want failed assert statements to result in a test failure on the report. This enables me to differentiate between tests which failed or ones which have an error in the unit test code. Is there a way to configure the generated xml reports to report assertion errors as failures?

Edit: I found that one workaround would be to add a try block around the test case then

```
       catch (AssertionError ae) {
         fail(ae.toString());
       }
```

however, from documentation, I read this should be unnecessary. Also since I am working on a large project, it would take a long time to add this to every test. Additionally, I would worry about not catching real errors and about compatibility issues with running outside of ant. Furthermore, it isn't as easy to find the source of the failure. So I am hoping to find a better solution.

Comment: your setup is not reproduceable. Can you please edit your question and add the full ant script file and also your test case code. Which Java and JUnit version are you using?

Comment: @AndersLindgren I updated my question. I can't post the code since the VM I am working from does not connect to the internet but I retyped it here.

Answer (score 0):

You have some small errors in your ant file, so you will have to read the ant manual closely to get all the bits.

if you call your ant file `build.xml` you can call `ant` without giving the `-buildfile` flag.

I created the following directories in my project directory

```
build
java
junit-results
lib
test
```

and put the `junit-4.4.jar` file in the `lib` directory.

I do recommend to use the [maven directory structure](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) if possible, but
I guess that you have an old project and can't change the structure.

```xml
<project name="JUnitTest" default="test" basedir=".">
    <property name="srcdir" location="java" />
    <property name="testdir" location="test" />
    <property name="classdir" location="build" />
    <property name="resultdir" location="junit-results" />
    <property name="full-compile" value="true" />

    <path id="classpath.test">
        <pathelement location="${classdir}" />
        <pathelement location="lib/junit-4.4.jar" />
    </path>

    <target name="compile">
        <javac srcdir="${srcdir}" destdir="${classdir}">
        </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="compileTests" depends="compile">
        <javac srcdir="${testdir}" destdir="${classdir}">
            <classpath refid="classpath.test" />
        </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="test" depends="compileTests">
        <junit haltonfailure="no">
            <classpath refid="classpath.test" />
            <formatter type="xml" />
            <test name="MyUnitTest" todir="${resultdir}" />
        </junit>
    </target>
</project>
```